# Libgdx assetManager

Tags: android, libgdx

I use AssetManager in my game to load 2 skins. To show a loading screen I need an image so I load it firstly and while skins are loading I use that image for animating loading screen.  When I run the game on an android device, the loading screen animation stops in the middle of it and starts playing after all assets are loaded. So what is it?
 1. Does the AssetManager blocks the rendering thread for some assets, and if not, why then my simple animation lags?
 2. How to show animated loading screen without any lag?

Note: I did call the assetManager.update().

```
@Override
public void show() {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(SplashStage.instance());
    assetManager = new AssetManager();
    assetManager.load("skin/loadingSkin", Skin.class);
    assetManager.load("skin/mainSkin", Skin.class);
}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    SplashStage.instance().act();
    SplashStage.instance().draw();
    TweenController.instance().getTweenManager().update(delta);
    Table.drawDebug(SplashStage.instance());

    if (assetManager.update()) {
        if (splashComplete) {
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        }
    }

    if (assetManager.isLoaded("skin/loadingSkin", Skin.class) && !splashStarted) {
        splashStarted = true;
        splashSkin = assetManager.get("skin/loadingSkin", Skin.class);
        TweenController.instance().registerAccessors();
        loadSplash();
    }

}


private void loadSplash() {
    loadingLabel = new Label("Loading...", splashSkin, ParameterConstants.FONT_SIZE_2);
    loadingLabel.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - loadingLabel.getWidth() / 2,
                             Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - loadingLabel.getHeight() * 4);
    loadingLabel.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    SplashStage.instance().addActor(loadingLabel);
    float ratio =  (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 2 / 3 / logoImage.getWidth());
    logoImage.setSize(logoImage.getWidth() * ratio, logoImage.getHeight() * ratio);
    logoImage.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - logoImage.getWidth() / 2,
                          Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - logoImage.getHeight() / 2);
    SplashStage.instance().addActor(logoImage);

    TweenAnimation.logoAnimation(logoImage, loadingLabel, new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            splashComplete = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using for your loading screen.

Comment: Furthermore if your loading Screen is ONLY loading 2 skins, then it might indeed be the defined behaviour. I think the AssetManager just tracks the already loaded assets as his progress. So in case you have only two assets it will only have three steps: 0%, 50% and 100%. Since you are probably switching the Screen at 100%, 50% is probably the only state you will see before changing the screen.

Comment: So this is my code. Tween animation changes the dimensions of the actor in a different thread. I thought it could somehow matter. I made simple animation in a game thread but it did stop either. So I think this is because AssetManager block rendering thread somehow.